# redirect to page for one time when user open the website for first time

Tags: php, session, laravel

How I can make redirection to page for one time when user open the website for first time?
(by `laravel` preferred)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the user has the cookie. If does have, redirect, else, set the cookie and let it be.

Comment: What if the user deletes the cookie?

Comment: @Daan sessions are based on cookie, too.

Comment: Yes so what are you trying to say?

Comment: What if the user deletes the session cookie and loses the session? I really don't think he needs this kind of guarantee. Also, in many places, IPs are shared.

Comment: Agree with the last thingy

Answer (score -1):

Save the IP adress in a database and check if the IP is already there. If not insert it and make the redirect:

```
Redirect::to('user/firsttime')->with('message', 'Welcome this is your first time here');
```

Comment: There is no point in using session, even less using a database! If sessions alone would hold the information you need, why accessing a database? Also, a cookie is better suited for this scenario.

Comment: You don't need to create a session for this. `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` ?